# page refresh detection code not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I found a nice article on how to detect page refresh in this article: [Detecting browser 'Refresh' from Code behind in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2011/06/08/detecting-browser-refresh-from-code-behind-in-.net.aspx), I tried to follow the code and use it in a web form application written in vb.net.

My problem is that when I refresh the page using the browser refresh button, the boolean IsPageRefresh, always remains false. So the code that I am trying to prevent from executing on page refresh, keeps getting executed.

Here is an example if my vb.net code including the converted code from the article:

```
Dim IsPageRefresh As Boolean = False

Protected Sub Account_reset_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ViewState("ViewStateId") = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        Session("SessionId") = ViewState("ViewStateId").ToString()
    Else
        If ViewState("ViewStateId").ToString() <> Session("SessionId").ToString() Then
            IsPageRefresh = True
        End If
        Session("SessionId") = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        ViewState("ViewStateId") = Session("SessionId").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Account_reset_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        If Not IsPageRefresh Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request("key")) Then
                If Not (Customer.SignInByResetKey(Request("key"))) Then
                    Customer.Messages.Add("Invalid password reset key", MessageType.Error)
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
                    Functions.Redirect(SiteLink.ResetPassword)
                Else
                    ' Do Nothing
                End If
            Else                    
                Functions.Redirect(SiteLink.ResetPassword)
            End If
        Else
            'Do Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like to ask for help to try to identify where I possibly am making the mistake, or if there is a better method.

I saw many articles that show how to catch page refresh in code behind, but they use the PreRender method, and I cannot implement that solution due to how to website was built.

I hope I can get some positive feedback.

Many thanks.

Comment: P.S. This solution will not work with if user opens several tabs

Comment: Is there another solution that you can recommend? Thank you

Comment: No. The web is stateless. Why do you want to detect refreshes anyways?

Comment: To prevent a second run of code that is executed when page first loads.

Comment: Well there's an easy way around that. In your web application, update some sort of flag that you store in Session or database or other persistent storage. Before you run the code, check the flag to see if it's already running. Problem solved, and you didn't have to fight the stateless web. This is an example of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could have prevented this by clearing explaining your problem and intended solution rather than dictating the solution.

Comment: Thank mason for pointing out the article about XY Problem. Would you recommend I rewrite my question? I would like to learn how to store the flag using session.